If statement in Dax Power bi ; Calling upon existing measure
So i have a measure that looks at YTD values of of Targets column and Values column and based on that gives the information if the KPI is Green,Red or Yellow.
When displayed i an card it needs to be filrered by singular value of additional column  (name of KPi) so it works.
Now my problem comes when i want to create another measure that will look at output of 2 Kpi names (output from original measure) and work with logic:
Both are Green, its green
One is green other yelow, its green
Other cases its red
How can i achive this?
Thank you upfront!
I tried uaing two nested switch statements, but again it only forces one filters value on visual, where i expect it to alow mr to chose 2 and then go with the logic.
